# Do all the random variables in the exponential family form a semi-group w.r.t. the random variable summation?

Tags: probability-theory, summation

Assume the distributions of $X$ and $Y$ are in an exponential family (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family). Then, does "$X+Y$ is in some exponential family" always hold?

Thanks!

Comment: Oh I see, I guess you probably mean [*this exponential family*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family).

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks for your comments! I have added a link to illustrate the exponential family :-)

Comment: 1) Without the assumption of independence, this cannot hold, of course. 2) Also check the articles before "exponential family". If the second is "the" indeed, then the answer is negative: exponential distributions form an exponential family, but it is not closed under addition. So should it be "an" perhaps?

Comment: @zhoraster Thanks a lot! I have revised my question accordingly for your second comment. For the first comment, what if $X$ and $Y$ are independent? Thanks!

Comment: Still looks unlikely. In some cases, yes, but in general there seems to be no reason why this should be true. Where does the question come from?

Comment: @zhoraster Thanks! Recently, I am focusing on the stable distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution), which has this property. So, I am just curious if distributions in exponential family have this property, too.

Comment: You probably know that the stable distributions do not belong to exponential families. Speaking of exponential families which add up to something from exponential family... I can name binomial, Poisson, negative binomial, gamma, normal. Can't think of anything else; is that enough?

Comment: Yes, you are right -- most of stable distributions are not in exponential families. Thanks very much for your examples. Your comments also shed light on my question. In general, this property cannot hold, since the convolution of two pdfs might not have the pdf form of exponential families (sometimes, the convolution would not have a closed-form expression, e.g., X follows a uniform distribution and Y follows a normal distribution).

Comment: Just realized that the inverse Gaussian distributions are also exponential family closed under addition.

Comment: @zhoraster Thanks very much!